# Embedding code (css, js) into a document on high profile sites

Tags: performance, page-load-time

Is there an advantage of some sort (speed or performance wise) to embed your CSS and JS into your web page, as opposed to keeping the code in sparate files? I was raised to believe that keeping code separate in separate files makes things easier to maintain. However, on high profile websites like amazon or google even facebook, I see a lot of embed code. Is there a performance reason they choose to do so or is it just an old/new way of doing things. I suppose my question is similar to this one: [Should I inline CSS & JS in mobile sites to save bandwidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732102/should-i-inline-css-js-in-mobile-sites-to-save-bandwidth)

But I would like to hear form experts, most notably from people who worked on high profile web sties and have done so, if any.

P.S.

Bonus Question: Last html comment on amazon web pages is `<!-- MEOW -->` does it mean anything or is it just a funny prank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stoyan did an experiment that you might find interesting http://www.phpied.com/style-tag-to-inline-style-attrrib/

Answer (score 1):

There are good reasons to inline resources, but as with most things, it also has its tradeoffs. The simplest case for inlining is cases where the cost of an HTTP connection is much more than the resource itself, ex: if you have a 10x10 icon you need to show, a dedicated request for that may not be worth it vs. inlining the data via a data URI.

This is especially true when and if you have many small resources that need to be fetchd. Most browsers limit themselves to a max of 6 connections per host, so if you have 60 resources which need to be fetched, then you'll be blocked for a significant chunk of time.

To work around these case we've invented other workarounds: domain sharding to go over the 6 connection limit, and "spriting" to fetch one resource vs multiple.

If you take a look at mod_pagespeed (Apache module), which does many of these optimizations on the fly for you, then the recommended setting we provide is to inline any resource that's below 2kb. That's a pretty good rule of thumb for today's stack.

Once SPDY is more widely deployed, many of these workarounds can be eliminated: no need to do domain sharding, cost of extra requests is much less, etc.

Answer (score 0):

CSS/JS external files typically get cached on the user's hard drive under that users browser's profile. So unless you change the code frequently, you won't really be doing yourself a favor by putting it inline.

Definitely saves you time from maintenance, but you can easily call in a javascript/css file and embed the code on the page you're populating on the server side, but that also means you're making your server do additional work.

As for the MEOW - yeah, them trying to be funny, or it's code... for... cat...